# hchart Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `x` is of unsupported type quoted call

Tags: r, highcharts, compiler-errors

I have the following data

```
> temp_data %>% head(15) %>% select(title,voteCount)
# A tibble: 15 x 2
                                                                            title voteCount
                                                                           <fctr>     <int>
 1                                                            Forrest Gump (1994)     91921
 2                                               Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)     91082
 3                                                            Pulp Fiction (1994)     87901
 4                                               Silence of the Lambs, The (1991)     84078
 5                                                             Matrix, The (1999)     77960
 6                                      Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)     77045
 7                                                           Jurassic Park (1993)     74355
 8                                                        Schindler's List (1993)     67662
 9                                                              Braveheart (1995)     66512
10                                                               Toy Story (1995)     66008
11                              Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)     62714
12                                              Terminator 2: Judgment Day (1991)     61836
13                          Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)     61672
14                                                              Fight Club (1999)     60024
15 Raiders of the Lost Ark (Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark) (1981)     59693
```

I want to create a bar-plot using hchart for this using this line of code

```
hchart(head(temp_data,15), hcaes(x=title, y=voteCount), type="column") %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google())
```

It was working before, but then I updated some of the packages in my RStudio and after that whenever I try to run this line it gives me the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `x` is of unsupported type quoted call
```

I don't know which update caused it and I can't find it, I tried searching for the problem and found [this thread](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/420) but couldn't find anything that could solve my problem.

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2        arulesViz_1.3-1     wordcloud2_0.2.0    arules_1.6-1       
 [5] Matrix_1.2-11       tidytext_0.1.8      tm_0.7-3            NLP_0.1-11         
 [9] stringi_1.1.7       stringr_1.3.0       magrittr_1.5        data.table_1.10.4-3
[13] plotly_4.7.1        tidyr_0.8.1         ggplot2_3.0.0       highcharter_0.5.0  
[17] dplyr_0.7.4         readr_1.1.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-131         bitops_1.0-6         xts_0.10-1           lubridate_1.7.2     
 [5] httr_1.3.1           prabclus_2.2-6       SnowballC_0.5.1      tools_3.4.2         
 [9] DT_0.4               R6_2.2.2             KernSmooth_2.23-15   lazyeval_0.2.1      
[13] colorspace_1.3-2     trimcluster_0.1-2    nnet_7.3-12          withr_2.1.2         
[17] gridExtra_2.3        mnormt_1.5-5         curl_3.0             compiler_3.4.2      
[21] TSP_1.1-6            xml2_1.2.0           labeling_0.3         slam_0.1-42         
[25] diptest_0.75-7       caTools_1.17.1       scales_0.5.0         lmtest_0.9-36       
[29] DEoptimR_1.0-8       mvtnorm_1.0-7        psych_1.7.8          robustbase_0.93-0   
[33] digest_0.6.12        foreign_0.8-69       pkgconfig_2.0.1      htmltools_0.3.6     
[37] htmlwidgets_1.2      rlang_0.2.1          TTR_0.23-3           quantmod_0.4-12     
[41] visNetwork_2.0.4     bindr_0.1            zoo_1.8-1            jsonlite_1.5        
[45] mclust_5.4           gtools_3.5.0         dendextend_1.8.0     tokenizers_0.2.1    
[49] rlist_0.4.6.1        modeltools_0.2-21    Rcpp_0.12.15         munsell_0.4.3       
[53] viridis_0.5.1        scatterplot3d_0.3-41 whisker_0.3-2        yaml_2.1.14         
[57] MASS_7.3-47          flexmix_2.3-14       gplots_3.0.1         plyr_1.8.4          
[61] parallel_3.4.2       gdata_2.18.0         lattice_0.20-35      hms_0.4.1           
[65] knitr_1.17           pillar_1.2.3         igraph_1.2.1         fpc_2.1-11          
[69] reshape2_1.4.2       codetools_0.2-15     stats4_3.4.2         glue_1.2.0          
[73] gclus_1.3.1          vcd_1.4-4            foreach_1.4.4        gtable_0.2.0        
[77] purrr_0.2.5          kernlab_0.9-25       assertthat_0.2.0     broom_0.4.2         
[81] janeaustenr_0.1.5    class_7.3-14         viridisLite_0.3.0    seriation_1.2-3     
[85] tibble_1.4.2         iterators_1.0.9      registry_0.5         cluster_2.0.6
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds obvious, but have you tried restarting your R session?

Comment: @camille yes, 20 times

Comment: That's what I figured but thought I'd throw it out there. On that GH thread, it looks like there were compatibility issues with versions of `ggplot2` and `highcharter`. I see you have the most recent `ggplot2`, but some people on the thread say the dev version of `highcharter` works. Can you try that? `devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")`

Comment: @camille I had done this twice and everytime my Rstudio crashed, after 3 more crashes, and updating and installing many other libraries while installing the developer version it works now (I had to restart it again in the end) thanks for your help

Comment: camile's approach worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same issue. Installed the development version 0.6.0. Its working fine now.**

Or modify your code as follows and it should work.

```
temp_data <- head(temp_data)

highchart() %>% 
hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = temp_data$title) %>% 
hc_add_series(data = temp_data$voteCount,
name = "temp data",colorByPoint = TRUE)%>% 
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google())
```

Comment: Since my problem was solved by @camille 's approach from the question's comments I can't be sure to verify this as the right answer, please tell me if anyone found this solution valid. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to above.  I was prompted to update a few of the package dependencies. However, my version of Rcpp was not updating properly.  I reinstalled the package and loaded the dev version of highcharter.  Then I restarted my r session and ran my code and voila.  It worked!